# Where does this has_many through: association go wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

Desired outcome:

`Item.first.ratings` gives me the ratings of that item.

Desired tables and columns:

```
item
  id,name,created_at,updated_at
ratings
  id,name,created_at,updated_at
item_ratings
  id,item_id,rating_id,value,created_at,updated_at
```

ratings migration:

```
class CreateRatings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :ratings do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

join table migration:

```
class CreateJoinTableItemsRatings < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :items, :ratings do |t|
      t.index [:item_id, :rating_id]
      t.index [:rating_id, :item_id]
      t.string :value
    end
  end
end
```

item model:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :item_ratings
   has_many :ratings, through: :item_ratings
end
```

rating model:

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :item_ratings
  has_many :items, through: :item_ratings
end
```

item_rating model:

```
class ItemRating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :rating
end
```

1. `rails console`
2. `Item.first.ratings`

result:

```
Item Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" ORDER BY "items"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]   
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "item_ratings" does not exist
    LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"item_ratings"'::regclass
                                              ^
    :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                         pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                 (SELECT c.collname FROM pg_collation c, pg_type t
                   WHERE c.oid = a.attcollation AND t.oid = a.atttypid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation),
                         col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                    FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                      ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                   WHERE a.attrelid = '"item_ratings"'::regclass
                     AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                   ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Question:
Where does this has_many through: association go wrong? Is this the right question to ask?

Comment: Did you try reloading the console with `reload!`

Comment: Yes I did, multiple times, also exiting and going back. Checked with multiple tutorials where I went wrong, but all seems okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table `item_ratings` does not exist but `items_ratings` does, try renaming all occurrences of `item_ratings` to `items_ratings`.

Comment: This is correct, yous should change `has_many :item_ratings` to `has_many :items_ratings`